# Kong refuses to recognise custom plugin as enabled

Tags: nginx, plugins, lua, mashape, kong

I was developing a Custom plugin for Kong.

To start off I followed guidelines listed in this tutorial

http://streamdata.io/blog/developing-an-helloworld-kong-plugin/

Few changes that I made along the way were changing dependency in the rockspec file for "lrexlib-pcre" from version 2.8.0-1 to 2.7.2-1 due to compilation problems that I faced with 2.8.0-1 version.
Please note that I am working in the next branch. The master branch has version 2.7.2-1 listed.

The tutorial assumes Kong version 0.4.2-1 while I am working with Kong version 0.5.2-1.

I have listed my plugin in kong.yml. Last listed is helloworld plugin

```
    plugins_available:
  - ssl
  - jwt
  - acl
  - cors
  - oauth2
  - tcp-log
  - udp-log
  - file-log
  - http-log
  - key-auth
  - hmac-auth
  - basic-auth
  - ip-restriction
  - mashape-analytics
  - request-transformer
  - response-transformer
  - request-size-limiting
  - rate-limiting
  - response-ratelimiting
  - helloworld
```

I have listed the helloworld files in rockspec file at the last.

> ["kong.plugins.helloworld.handler"] =
>   "kong/plugins/helloworld/handler.lua",
>       ["kong.plugins.helloworld.access"] = "kong/plugins/helloworld/access.lua",
>       ["kong.plugins.helloworld.schema"] = "kong/plugins/helloworld/schema.lua"

Compilation is successful but kong refuses to list helloworld plugin as available in the node. All other builtin plugins are shown as available in the server

I tried enabling the plugin anyway with mock api. It doesn't work as expected and trying to restart kong lists error

> nginx: [error] [lua] init_by_lua:5: Startup error:
>   /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong.lua:82: You are using a plugin that has
>   not been enabled in the configuration: helloworld [INFO] dnsmasq
>   stopped [ERR] Could not start Kong

I know there were some breaking changes introduced in Kong version 0.5. I followed the changelog, but I found nothing that would help.

Am i missing a setting a configuration somewhere?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: the official plugin development guide is now out: https://getkong.org/docs/0.5.x/plugin-development/ would be worth checking it against what you're doing in case something was missed

Comment: Hi, did you fix this issue already? I've been playing around with Kong and customs plugins for a while and they are kind of tricky. I had your issue a few times but it was because I was modifying the wrong kong.yml. Usually when you install Kong from an rpm the conf file is in /etc/kong/kong.yml but if you are developing locally when you run "make start" it'll use kong_DEVELOPMENT.yml. If you run "bin/kong start" it ill use the kong.yml in your working directory. Make sure you are editing the proper one (or just edit all of them)

Comment: I just had exactly same problem make sure you change **/etc/kong/kong.yml** !

Answer (score 0):

Try the following  in your `kong.yml`:

```
custom_plugins:
  - helloworld
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by adding things in **custom_plugins and lua_package_path.**

Here are the steps to enable and use custom plugin in kong Env.

1 - Add custom plugin name in --- **custom_plugins = hello-world**

2 - Install hello-world plugin by using following steps ---

If you have source code of your plugin then move into it and execute the command --- **"luarocks make"**

it will install your plugin.

now you have to execute a command **"make install-dev"** make sure your plugin have makefile like as --

[image]

Once you execute this command **"make install-dev"**. it will create lua file at a location something like that -

/**your-plugin-path**/lua_modules/share/lua/5.1/kong/plugins/**your-plugin-name**/?.lua

just copy this path and add it into the kong configuration file in lua_package_path

Something like that --

**lua_package_path=/your-plugin-path/lua_modules/share/lua/5.1/kong/plugins/your-plugin-name/?.lua**

Now you done your job.

Just start kong -- **kong start --vv**

You will see that the plugin loaded into kong plugin env.

**@Enjoy**